# How to run unit test coverage report using coverlet inside a container?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, code-coverage

I'm using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 image to run unit tests inside a container. It is failing to generate coverage report by throwing following error.

```
error : One or more errors occurred. 
(Could not find file '/tmp/xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD [ "bash", "./build.sh" ]
```

build.sh

```
#!bin/bash

export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

echo "Installing Tools"
dotnet tool install --global coverlet.console

echo "Adding Package"
dotnet add <.csproj> package coverlet.msbuild

echo "Running Tests"
dotnet test <.csproj> /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover /p:CoverletOutput='./coverage/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with the `2.6.0` version of `coverlet`.

Hardcoding version solves the problem.

```
echo "Adding Package"
dotnet add <.csproj> package coverlet.msbuild --version 2.5.1
```